# Jenkins Integration with Liferay 7.1 using Gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-7.1

I need to integrate **sonarqube with liferay 7.1** using **gradle in jenkins** pipeline.

i have tried the below code in root workspace of the Liferay

```
stage('SonarQube Analysis') {
            steps {         
                withSonarQubeEnv(credentialsId: 'jenkins-token',, installationName: 'SONAR') {
                    dir("${GRADLE_ROOT_DIRECTORY}") {
                        bat "gradle sonarqube"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

> Error
>
> Task :sonarqube FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
>   Unable to execute SonarQube
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Also i need to know how we can run a Gradle command for specific project inside a Liferay workspace.

Comment: Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: how we can run gradle command for specific project inside liferay -> use 
 gradlew :project:subject:taskName